# frenchstemmer library i java input in file?

Tags: java

I found a library to stemm french words. I've found some code to test it, and I just need to read in a file, apply the code logic, and then output the results to another file.

Here is the stemming code I have so far:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.tartarus.snowball.SnowballStemmer;
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.frenchStemmer;


public class SnowballfrenchStemmerTest {

@Test
public void testSnowbalfrenchStemmer() {

    SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) new frenchStemmer();

    String[] tokens = "attacher attachement attaché ".split(" ");    
    for (String string : tokens) {
        stemmer.setCurrent(string);
        stemmer.stem();
        String stemmed = stemmer.getCurrent();

        System.out.println(stemmed);
    }

}
```

Comment: So... what's your question?  If it's just "how do I read from/write to a file in Java", there are oodles of tutorials all over the web on how to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must read from file. Try to use sth. like `new String(Files.readAllBytes(path to your file))`

Or

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

                String sCurrentLine;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\path\testing.txt"));
                SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) new frenchStemmer();

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split(" ");    
                        for (String string : tokens) {
                            stemmer.setCurrent(string);
                            stemmer.stem();
                            String stemmed = stemmer.getCurrent();

                            System.out.println(stemmed);
                        }
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                try {
                        if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: im trying with BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/test.txt")); // you can change file path.
  
    Scanner filesc=new Scanner(in);//scanner for file
   PrintWriter out =  new PrintWriter (new FileWriter ("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/result.txt")) ; but i don t get a result